# return type According to logic

Tags: c#

I'm using c# and I'm using CQRS
So let's image this scenario

```
public async Task<Response<SaleProducts>> Handle(CreateSaleProductCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var newEntity = MyCustomerMapper.Mapper.Map<SaleProducts>(request);
                if (newEntity is null)
                    throw new ApplicationException("There is a problem in mapper");

                var itemToReturn = await _repositoryCommand.AddProductToSaleAsync(newEntity);
                if(itemToReturn != null)
                {
                    itemToReturn.Product = await _productQueryRepository.GetByIdAsync(itemToReturn.ProductId);  
                    return new Response<SaleProducts>(itemToReturn);
                }
                else
                    throw new ApplicationException("There is a problem when saving the product");


            }
```

so this function return `Response<SaleProducts>` after saving.

Now I like to make some verification in my `_repositoryCommand.AddProductToSaleAsync`.

So if verification is ok I return SaleProducts if not I return other value(like bool or string) for exepmle.

So is there any way to have something similar to this

```
 public async Task<Response<SaleProducts | bool>> Handle(CreateSaleProductCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

return type `SaleProducts | bool | string`

Comment: The cleanest approach most likely would be Options<Monad> however the very fact that your method may return different types is a smell that it may have to much responsibility.

Comment: If the Response<T> class you are using is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.response-1?view=azure-dotnet can't you take advantage of the `HasValue` property and if `HasValue` is false meaning there is no valid value in the response, then that would be the same as returning false in your validation logic?

Answer (score 3):

There is no build-in way to represent that in C# (unless count [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) as one, but personally I prefer to use it when all elements can be present in the result). You can look into using [`Either` monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/05/09/an-either-monad/) from some existing libraries like [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext):

```cs
public async Task<Response<Either<string, SaleProducts>>> Handle()
```

Or [`OneOf`](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf):

> This library provides F# style <strike>discriminated</strike> unions for C#, using a custom type OneOf<T0, ... Tn>. An instance of this type holds a single value, which is one of the types in its generic argument list.

Which referes the similar problem as one of the common to solve with `OneOf`:

> The most frequent use case is as a return value, when you need to return different results from a method.

```cs
public OneOf<User, InvalidName, NameTaken> CreateUser(string username)
{
    if (!IsValid(username)) return new InvalidName();
    var user = _repo.FindByUsername(username);
    if(user != null) return new NameTaken();
    var user = new User(username);
    _repo.Save(user);
    return user;
}
```

And provides handy methods to work with it.

Or [`FluentResults`](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults):

> FluentResults is a lightweight .NET library developed to solve a common problem. It returns an object indicating success or failure of an operation instead of throwing/using exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just use a tuple for this:

```
public async Task<Response<(SaleProducts? Products, string? Status)>> Handle(CreateSaleProductCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Then your `Handle` turns into:

```
public async Task<Response<SaleProducts>> Handle(CreateSaleProductCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var newEntity = MyCustomerMapper.Mapper.Map<SaleProducts>(request);
                if (newEntity is null)
                    throw new ApplicationException("There is a problem in mapper");

                var (itemToReturn, textStatus) = await _repositoryCommand.AddProductToSaleAsync(newEntity);
                if(itemToReturn != null)
                {
                    itemToReturn.Product = await _productQueryRepository.GetByIdAsync(itemToReturn.ProductId);  
                    return new Response<SaleProducts>(itemToReturn);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do whatever processing you want to do with textStatus
                    ...
                    throw new ApplicationException("There is a problem when saving the product");
                }


            }
```